# Cancellation propriety for continuous functions.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let's say we have a continuous (onto) function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exist $k,s \in \mathbb{N}: f^k=f^s$. Is it true that $f^{|k-s|}=id$? Is it true something similar?

Comment: Simple counterexample: $f(x) = x$, for $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$, $f(x) = -1$ for $x < -1$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x > 1$. Then $f^k = f$, for all $k \geqslant 1$ but no $f^n$ for $n > 0$ is the identity. It's easy to transform that to higher dimensions.

Comment: What if I ask to be onto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ onto, then the continuous condition for $f$ is superfluous.

Since $f$ is onto, so is $f^s$.

So from the condition that $f^{s + k} = f^s$, we obtain: $f^k\circ f^s = f^{s + k} = f^s = \text{id}\circ f^s$, since $f^s$ is onto, we can cancel $f^s$ on the right to obtain $f^k = \text{id}$.